# string.Join error, the separator doesn't show on the string

Tags: c#, string, entity-framework, join, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a class Articulos where i have a column with the name Genero that is a ICollection. In the view i have a multiple select list that is attached to it, what i do to save the selection is in the ApplicationDBContext i convert the ICollection to a long string with string.Join() and save it.

The problem is that the string it save without the separator, in my case i using ",", but is like the method ignore it.

Here is the column on the Class:

```
[Required]
 public ICollection<string> Genero { get; set; }
```

This is part of the Db Context:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Articulo>().Property(e => e.Genero)
                .HasConversion(
                v => string.Join(",", v),
                v => v.Split(",", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

When i save the string it supposed to show something like: 
Terror,Suspenso,Animada...

But instead it shows me: 
TerrorSuspensoAnimada

I'm working on ASP.Net Core 2.2

Comment: Can you share what `HasConversion` is/does?

Comment: It's a method fthat configures the property so the value is converted to the given type before writing to the database and converted back when reading from database. [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.propertybuilder.hasconversion?view=efcore-2.1) @John

Comment: What is the _compile-time_ type of the first `v`, that is the `v` in `string.Join(",", v)`? Can you hold the mouse over that `v` and see what it says? You probably get another overload of `Join` than you think. If you try instead, `string.Join(",", v.AsEnumerable())`, what happens? EDIT: I see you write `','` in the question. Can you check and see if you do not have `","` in the real code? Please make the question code as precise as possible.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen, sorry, it was a mistake is ",". About your question, when i hold the mouse over the v it says: (parameter) IColecction<string> v. I did what you suggest and mark a error: ICollection doesn't contain a definition for AsEnumerable() and not accessible method found.

Comment: OK, `AsEnumerable()` requires a `using System.Linq;` directive in the top of the file. But it will probably not solve anything. To @John, I think `HasConversion` may be this overload: [`PropertyBuilder<TProperty>.HasConversion<TProvider>` overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.builders.propertybuilder-1.hasconversion#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Metadata_Builders_PropertyBuilder_1_HasConversion__1_System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func__0___0___System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0__0___)